# How to use custom group key in JdbcMessageStore in Spring Integration Aggregator

Tags: spring-integration

We are using Spring Integration Aggregator to aggregate list of line item for a given order. Now we do store group message info in db. But what we noticed is that it is using `UUID` kind of value as group_key in table `INT_MESSAGE_GROUP` table. Is it possible to customize this to use order id (always unique in our system) so that we can troubleshoot aggregation issue in production envt by running query against the db by order id.

I did noticed that internal it is using Correlation key as group key but not sure why it did not used our Correlation key(which is order id) since we configured our custom Correlation strategy in aggregator configuration.

Fyi we are using spring integration 4.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since we configured our custom Correlation strategy in aggregator configuration.

The `AggregatingMessageHandler` has a logic:

```
Object correlationKey = this.correlationStrategy.getCorrelationKey(message);
...
UUID groupIdUuid = UUIDConverter.getUUID(correlationKey);
```

So, if your `correlationStrategy` is correct, you have `correlationKey` as your `order id`.

Although yes, it will be still as an `UUID` in the DB.

That's because an `UUID` is exactly `CHAR(36)` and fully compatible between different RDBMS vendors.

We have an open [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2675) on the matter, but I fully don't believe that it is reasonable to blow DB with custom String keys with different lengths.

Consider to find (or write) some DB function to build similar `UUID` based on your `order id` key for those troubleshooting queries.

Or... just provide some Groovy script for your customers to get that `UUID` string using `java.util.UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes('myOrderId'.bytes).toString()` from Java!

Comment: Thanks Artem for your input. I think we can live with what is provided by JdbcMessageStore for now.